# Using Capybara to interact with lazy loading elements

Tags: ruby, capybara

Currently I have trouble in with interacting with the elements within the page using lazy loading. I need to select the list of items (which mostly from top till the bottom of page, up to like 100 items). With the lazy loading implemented, i could only select a portion of it, like 1/3 of that since they split all the items into 3 different portions then it will only load the the first portion. I found out using a `tricky` Javascript could help to scroll it to the bottom like `page.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,100000)")`, then i could probably get all the items.

but should be saving that as the last option.

So, my question is *Does Capybara support to interact with Lazy Loading stuff* like that . Also what should I do to get the whole items, without using that Javascript ?

Comment: Are you testing an app, or just scraping data from a site?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just scraping data from a site then the easiest solution is going to be just using `execute_script` to scroll the page.  If however you're testing an app behaves correctly then you want to stay away from `execute_script` since it can allow you to do things a user never could which may invalidate your tests. Instead use `hover` to move the mouse pointer over an element on the page that would trigger loading the next portion.  For instance if you have a list of items showing up

```
<ul id="my_list_of_items">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  ...
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

and the next group of items are loaded into the page when the bottom of the list is scrolled into view then do something like

```
find('.item:last-child').hover
```

This will cause the last item element on the page to be scrolled into view and the move pointer moved over it, which would then trigger loading of more items.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Thomas , actually I just wanna scrape data from website then get about like 10 samples from the list of data I get. It was fine before by just using `execute_script` then i got the things i want. Unfortunately, right now with the lazy loading, it must have been scrolled over and over from the top to bottom until the JS script finish then i could have the whole data i want. Using your solution is not applicable in this case cause the selector i wanna test is one of the attribute like `data-test-id = ...` (which has been set for testing purpose), was not the fixed class/id

Comment: Beside that, i managed to use the `execute_script` to get the data i want. However, since it was async, so before the JS finished (~ 40 secs) , it has the data that i use for assertion, which triggered the next step to run when it wasn't really finishing. So i wonder if there's something that i could use to implicit wait at this stage or even overriding the default waiting time of Capybara just for waiting  for JS script running to be finished ? Thanks

Comment: @DinhLuong it would still apply, you just need to change the selector to something that would match the last item in the list - `#list > li:last-child`, etc - However since you’re scraping execute_script is easier and just as valid.